# Vanishing of covariant divergence of a superpotential term

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus

I am working out the details in the [thesis](https://gwic.ligo.org/thesisprize/2012/butcher-thesis.pdf) of Luke Butcher, wherein, on page 64, he claims the following:

> [...] of  “superpotential”  terms,  those  fields  whose  divergence 
>   vanishes identically. Because these terms are of the
>   form $\nabla^{c}\nabla^{d}H_{[ac][bd]}$ (where $H_{[ac][bd]}=H_{[bd][ac]}$is some function of $h_{ab}$) [...]

I tried to prove that these expressions indeed vanish identically and defined $S_{acbd}=H_{[ac][bd]}$, which has the following symmetries: $S_{acbd}=-S_{cabd}=-S_{acdb}=S_{bdac}$.
The aforementioned terms can then be written as $\nabla^{c}\nabla^{d}S_{acbd} = S_{acbd;}^{\hspace{1.5em} dc}$.

Then I calculated the following divergence, changing the order of two outermost covariant derivatives using the Riemann tensor:

$$S_{acbd;}^{\hspace{1.5em} dca}=\frac{1}{2}S_{acbd;}^{\hspace{1.5em} dca} - \frac{1}{2}S_{cabd;}^{\hspace{1.5em} dca}=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\bigg{[}S_{acbd;}^{\hspace{1.5em} dca}-S_{cabd;}^{\hspace{1.5em} dac} + S_{mabd;}^{\qquad d}R^{m \hspace{0.4em}ac}_{\hspace{0.6em} c} + S_{cmbd;}^{\qquad d}R^{m \hspace{0.4em}ac}_{\hspace{0.6em} a}+S_{camd;}^{\qquad d}R^{m \hspace{0.4em}ac}_{\hspace{0.6em} b} +S_{cabm;}^{\hspace{1.8em} d}R^{m \hspace{0.4em}ac}_{\hspace{0.6em} d} - S_{cabd;}^{\hspace{1.5em} m}R^{d \hspace{0.7em}ac}_{\hspace{0.4em} m}\bigg{]}$$

All the terms except one either cancel with some other one, or vanish due to contractions of an antisymmetric tensor $S$ with a symmetric Ricci tensor.
I am left with:
$$\frac{1}{2} S_{camd;}^{\qquad d}R^{m \hspace{0.4em}ac}_{\hspace{0.6em} b}  $$

This one does not seem to vanish, which leads me to believe that either I made a mistake, or I am not seeing something trivial, or there is yet some calculation to be performed. I would be grateful for any suggestions.